# Is there a Sat Nav that works in Israel? (preferably with good coverage)

Tags: israel, electronic-items, gps-navigation

Does anyone know of a SatNav device or SatNav software for iPhone that has maps of Israel available (preferably with good coverage).

Answer (score 7):

[Waze](http://waze.com) is free and pretty good. It relies on the community for constructing the maps so it's not as good as Google Maps, but it has a lot of users in Israel (it's an Israeli company) so it provides excellent coverage.

Answer (score 5):

For example [Garmin](http://www.garmin.ch/de/c-PN246.html) offers a map that covers at least part of Israel.

Answer (score 3):

When I went to Israel I [jailbroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) my iPhone and installed [xGPS](http://xgps.xwaves.net/index.php/Main_Page), which worked great. xGPS basically downloads and caches Google Maps so you can use them even if you don't have an Internet connection.  It didn't give me turn-by-turn directions, however, it was great for navigating by foot in the cities.